# Android Date Format into custom date

Tags: java, android

In android in json i receive date string as "2018-03-13 19:00:00".
and i want to convert as "12-03-2018 07:00 PM".

So i have implemented few line of code.

```
    public static String getCustomDateScoreboard(String dateTimeStr) {
    Date date = null;
    String formattedTime = "";

    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(dateTimeStr);
        Log.d(TAG,date.toString());
        formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.US).format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "date time not in proper format: %s", dateTimeStr);
    }
    return formattedTime;
}
```

But it returns month as 00 i.e., 13-00-2018 07:00 PM

Comment: mm and MM is different options

Comment: You can change format according to you. Following link will help you in future. that is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

small `mm` is used for indicating minutes, use capital `MM` for month as in

```
public static String getCustomDateScoreboard(String dateTimeStr) {
    Date date = null;
    String formattedTime = "";

    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(dateTimeStr);
        Log.d(TAG,date.toString());
        formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.US).format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(e, "date time not in proper format: %s", dateTimeStr);
    }
    return formattedTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in date format in method like below ...

```
  public static String getCustomDateScoreboard() {
    Date date = null;
    String formattedTime = "";

    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse("2018-03-13 19:00:00"); // hear pass your receive date.
        Log.d("Time::",date.toString());
        formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.US).format(date);
        Log.d("Time2::",formattedTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    return formattedTime;
}
```